# Vue: Access component object inside methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to access an object of a component, but `this` in methods is references to the `methods: {}` object.

```
methods: {
  getInput: () => {
    return this.$refs.input.value
  }
}
```

I tried to invoke `getInput()`, but I am getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$refs' of undefined.

How can I access an object of a component instead of a `methods` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) You should use normal function instead of arrow one in order to get access to the component instance :

```
    methods: {
      getInput() {
        return this.$ref.input.value 
      }
    }
```

> Note that you should not use an arrow function to define a method (e.g. `plus: () => this.a++)`. The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.a` will be undefined.